# Create user with read only permission to datastore but SSH access

Tags: vmware-esxi, file-permissions, datastore

I am scripting a backup job in which a remote computer connects to an ESXi 5 host and does SCP to copy files to another datastore on that host.

As a precaution (since every script that can go wrong will go wrong) I want to prevent this script from being able to delete/move/rm files on one data store.

Is it possible to create a user that has READONLY permission to one datastore, but RW to another?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say don't do it on the host directly. ESXi's SSH interface isn't really meant for this sort of thing and leaving the service and shell enabled will trigger alarms and warnings to always appear in the clients. Yes, those alarms can be disabled, but they're there for a reason.

The approach I would take depends on the system from which you're planning to do this backup.

If it's Windows, I'd write some PowerCLI scripts and access the server that way. PowerCLI has commands built for this sort of thing and can do almost anything you can think of.

If it's Linux, there's the Perl modules that should allow pretty well the same thing, with a little more hacking away at it.

Some of this assumes that it's not just a single standalone ESXi host, and that you can leverage vCenter to grant a particular user some fine-grained permissions to do just these tasks.

I'd don't entirely remember what permissions model is setup on standalone hosts, but I suspect that you can create a user and do the same things. At least that way, you wouldn't have (possibly) runaway shell script executing on your ESXi box..

Comment: If it is a production environment I would also recommend using a backup software like vSphere Data Protection, Veeam, ... instead of scripting.